# EdSim51 Simulator: Octal Input using the Switches

Tags: assembly, binary, converters, octal, edsim51

As mentioned above, I have absolutely no idea on how to input octal numbers using the switches in the EdSim51 simulator. I do know that the "default" input using the switches comes in as binary in 1's complement.

We have a Design of Experiment (Octal to Binary Converter switches input/LEDs output) where the input uses the switches as input and outs in the LED(could prob just figure this out soon), but i just don't have a clue on how to input octal numbers using the switches...

Comment: I don't know what EdSim's UI looks like, but perhaps you're supposed to input the bit-patterns for ASCII digits that form an octal string representation of a number?  Otherwise yes, if your only input method is literal switches, that's already binary and the inputting `755` in octal would mean mentally converting that to groups of 3 bits to make the binary number.  Or perhaps separate each octal digit just so you can write a program to re-combine them into one contiguous binary bit pattern?

Comment: This is how the switches and the LEDs are arranged in the UI

[  ] [  ]  [  ] [  ] [  ]  [  ] [  ] [  ] - LEDs

[7] [6] [5] [4] [3] [2] [1] [0] - Switches (acts more like buttons tho hahahah)